# Sending Mail Through SendMail Using PHP

Tags: php, linux, email, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I am working on a basic Contact Us form that will send me a quick message from the user. The code is below. When I test it, no message is sent. However, I can send messages from command line using the `sendmail`.

Could someone tell me what I need to do to configure this setup? I have tried looking at PHP error logs but there was nothing there. Can I find `sendmail` logs somewhere?

Also, if this helps, the site is running on an AWS EC2 instance, with DNS configured through Route53 and is being served as a virtual host by the Apache.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0) {

    //$to = $_POST['to']['val']; // <=== Set static email here.
    $to = "xxxx@test.com";
    error_log("Entered the formdata.php script!", 0);
    error_log("To value:" . $to, 0);

    if (isset($_POST['formtype'])) {
        unset($_POST['formtype']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['to'])) {
        unset($_POST['to']);
    }
    error_log("To value:" . $to, 0);

    $email_address = $_POST['email']['val'];
    error_log("Email address:" . $email_address, 0);
    $email_subject = "Form submitted by: ".$_POST['name']['val'];
    $email_body    = "You have received a new message. <br/>".
                     "Here are the details: <br/><br/>";
                     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        $email_body .= "<strong>" . $value['label'] . ": </strong> " . $value['val'] . "<br/><br/>";
                     }

    $headers = "From:<$email_address>\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    if($email_address != "") {
        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You shoudn't use `mail()` yourself. Use a library instead, like PHPMailer. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - It can handle SMTP and attachments as well.

Comment: I have looked at that as well. Would that library not need be configured as well? Or is it pretty automatic after one has the `sendmail` working using the command line?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that. I used it with SMTP and a GMail Account which works fine.

Comment: Just basic in-PHP config, right?

Comment: Yes. Here's an example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps